# I want to solve a system of equations containing a*x

Tags: excel, solver, equations

Is it possible to solve a system of three equations in Excel, that contain x*y??

Let's suppose that my unknowns are `a,b,x`

The equations are

- `a + b = 1`
- `a * x - 20y = 0`
- `10x * a - 20a + b = 0`

Is there a way to express the multiplier that is one of my unknowns??

Answer (score 0):

here you can take z=x*a then your equations become:

- a + b = 1
- z - 20y = 0
- 10z - 20a + b = 0

Now solve these equation using simple method given [here](http://www.howtoexcel.info/excelsolver.htm). You get value of z and a. Now you can find value x. So finally you get value of a, b, z, y